# Hive table locks

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have hive tables which are queried through queries in a file. 
I had invoked an oozie workflow which invoked a hive action for mentioned file. 
The job did not succeed and I killed the workflow.

But the tables are still shown as locked on Hive CLI. I am looking for a command/process that will release locks from Hive tables.

Comment: "The job did not succeed and I killed the workflow."  What is the *exact* procedure you used to do this?

Comment: I killed it using oozie UI button "Kill"

Answer (score 16):

We can use the following query to release the lock

```
set hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DummyTxnManager; 
unlock table tablename;
```

Comment: I tried above command but got error 'Current transaction manager does not support explicit lock requests' .  I am using Hive 0.14.0.2.2.8.0-3150.

Answer (score 4):

if you use mysql as metastore, it will store table locks info in table HIVE_LOCKS, truncate it .

```
mysql> select * from HIVE_LOCKS;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
mysql>
```

Comment: This worked for me. By looking at the hive query ID in the HIVE_AGENT_INFO column and comparing to currently running queries, you can identify stale locks eg. locks from many days ago. 
You can then delete these only instead of truncating the whole table.

select HL_LOCK_EXT_ID, HL_LOCK_INT_ID, HL_DB, HL_TABLE, HL_AGENT_INFO from HIVE_LOCKS;

 delete from HIVE_LOCKS where HL_LOCK_EXT_ID in ( 123,456 );

Answer (score 3):

To Check the locks on table (Run in Hive)-

show locks *tablename* extended;

To find the activity id for long running query -  (You need to pass User from above query and can verify the Agent Info from first query with the application name in below query). Run outside hive

yarn application -list | grep *User*

To kill the activity id -

yarn application -kill *activityid*

Comment: `yarn applicatoin -list | grep userid` does not return any activity. But `show locks` lists so many tables.

Comment: ohk. But i tried with correct spelling, same result

Answer (score 1):

I also met a similar problem in hive3, and i read the source code in `org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.txn.TxnHandler`, i found that there is a function called `performTimeOuts()`, which is scheduled periodically by a daemon thread called `org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.txn.AcidHouseKeeperService`.

That daemon thread will clean outdated lock infomation automatically in the mysql table `hive.hive_locks`, but it is not enabled by default, so we just need to configure it in `hive-site.xml`, like this:

```
<property>
    <name>metastore.task.threads.always</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.events.EventCleanerTask,org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RuntimeStatsCleanerTask,org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.repl.DumpDirCleanerTask,org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.txn.AcidHouseKeeperService</value>
</property>
```

Comment: This solved the problem. AcidHouseKeeperService gets enabled with this.
Another config needed along with this is 


 `<property>
    <name>metastore.compactor.initiator.on</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>`